# How long should we keep the airflow scheduler running?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm very confused by how airflow picks up the changes in new DAG code with the scheduler. 
Can someone clarify how the airflow scheduler works with new code? Do I need to stop and rerun `airflow scheduler` every time I change code in DAGs? or can I just set `--num_runs 1`and run it every time I make new changes?

Thanks!

Comment: On the other hand we've had some issues with Airflow *not* picking up changes in DAGs and updates even if the webserver got restarted. So in our deployment routine we've implemented a restart of both components, the webserver and the scheduler.

Comment: I am also having issues in which I need to restart scheduler / webserver in order to pick up a newly added dag. Does anyone have a clue about that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scheduler should be running all the time. You should just run `airflow scheduler` without a `num_runs` param.  The scheduler is designed to be a long running process, an infinite loop.  It orchestrates the work that is being done, it is the heart of airflow. If it's not running, you aren't scheduling more work to be done.

Each iteration of the loop will reload what is called the `DagBag`, a collection of loaded DAGs. Any modifications to a DAG, as well as removal/addition of DAGs should be reflected the next scheduler loop.

Comment: Thanks! Please correct me if I'm wrong: If the changes happen in DAG files, `scheduler` would pick them up; but if the code changes happen in imported files (plugins, operators), then we need to stop and restart the `scheduler`. Is that right?

Comment: Nope, the scheduler will pick them up as well, I believe via a forked process.  There should never be a need to restart the scheduler to pick up code changes if you are adding them directly to your AIRFLOW_HOME.  There are more advanced use cases such as if you are running airflow in docker containers, where updating the container will cause the scheduler to restart (Which is how we run them for ourselves and our customers where I work, Astronomer).

Comment: "The scheduler should be running all the time" is not true. Here you can find for example a very old unresolved bug https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/7935 for which Airflow itself suggest to use the tuning (for example "run_duration") for fixing purposes

Comment: @marioquark in the context of the question, it is true. It is unnecessary to restart the scheduler to pick up changes in the dags, and therefore should remain running. My intent was to clear up confusion about how the scheduler works, not to imply that the scheduler should never be restarted for any reason. Airflow's bugginess around the scheduler all the sudden no longer scheduling is unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow's scheduler checks periodically and continuously the DAGs location to scan and refresh DAGs. If you didn't change the config, it's done with **just few seconds of pause between each round**.

The `--num_run` parameter was not introduced for refreshing purposes but for reliability:
Airflow officially advises [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/Scheduler+Basics) that **the scheduler should be restarted frequently** using the `num_runs` and/or the `run_duration` configuration parameters.

Comment: The link you provided is dead.